# Plot RGB image with matshow failed - Invalid shape

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, rgb

I have array with 12 bands:

```
array
(53, 44, 12)
```

I want to create RGB image from this array.
In order to do that I know that I need to slice the 3,2 and the 1 channels from the array and to create an image from them. In order to take those bands I have done this:

```
red=array[:,:,3]
green=array[:,:,2]
blue=array[:,:,1]

#stack together:
rgb=np.stack((red,green,blue))
```

The problem is that whenever I want to display the image as rgb I get error:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.matshow(rgb)
```

> TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 44, 12) for image data

My first idea to solve it was to change the order of the axis as I thought that it takes the 3 as number of rows, I have used np.moveaxis:

```
rgb=np.moveaxis(rgb, 0, -1).shape
rgb.shape
>>>
(44,12,3)
```

but then when I tried again with matshow I have got  error again:

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (3,) for image data
```

I'm not sure where is my mistake as in the past using matshow similarly worked.

**My end goal is to be able to plot the three bands as rgb image.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stack along the 3rd axis:

```
rgb = np.dstack((red,green,blue))
```

or

```
rgb = np.stack((red,green,blue), axis=2)
```

As [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088234/3944322) already pointed out you can do the same much easier by standard slicing. If the 12 bands of your `array` in fact represent 4 images (3 channels each) you could also split the array along axis 2 in 4 arrays like this:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = np.split(array, 4, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an image with 12 bands like this:

```
image[53,44,12]
```

and you want the first three bands, just use:

```
b0b1b2 = image[..., :3]
```

Check what you have with:

```
print(b0b1b2.shape)
(53, 44, 3)
```

This is Numpy [slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

---

If you want bands 0, 4 and 5, use

```
b0b4b5 = image[..., [0,4,5]]
```